# unix search a pattern on one column and remove those lines

Tags: unix

I am trying to search one column with a particular pattern, and eliminate those rows and create a new file without that pattern.

Sample Data:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
abc|test123|demo|test
def|test345|exam|write
ghf|456|test|account
ijk|789|travel|destination
```

Expected Output:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4
ghf|456|test|account
ijk|789|travel|destination
```

I want to search for the pattern "test" in 2nd column, and remove those rows from the source file, and create a new file as shown in the expected output.
File is a delimited file "|".

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"|" '{if(index($2,"test")==0) printf "%s\n", $0}' test > test_out
```

test is original file.

test_out is final expected file.

Comment: Shorter version : `awk -F'|' '$2 !~ /test/' original.txt > modified.txt`